# Replacing a 8 ohm Speaker with a Piezo. Will it work?

Tags: speakers, piezo-buzzer, piezo, substitution

Like [Replacing a piezoelectric speaker with an electromagnetic one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171358/replacing-a-piezoelectric-speaker-with-an-electromagnetic-one), but the other way round.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frTkT1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A DC squarewave will turn on and off ASW (Analog SWitch) for a buzzing sound from a constant voltage. The 4K7 pulldown is for discharging the cap. when ASW is open.

I want to use a piezo for the simplicity they provide.
Are the schematics equivalent, sound-wise?

Comment: No the schematics aren't equivalent.  I can tell because they are blatantly different.  One will clearly receive the square wave in series with a 1Mohm resistor, the other will not and even if it did, it'd be in series with a measly 8 ohm resistor.

Comment: @Funkyguy The cap+spkr one will still get a square wave, b/c caps pass AC components. But I will clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: Not if it is a DC square wave, unless it is a high enough frequency which you didn't specify,, it will still block much of the signal rendering the speaker useless

Comment: @Funkyguy Yes it will even if it's a DC square wave. They're merely AC square waves with the lowest point at GND.  Besides, it's for an audio project.

Comment: Why do you want to replace your speaker with a piezo? I get their cheaper, but their quality is blech

Comment: @Funkyguy I think the assumption is we're in the audio range, so relatively high frequency can be assumed.

Comment: Ok, that would have been nice to have in the original question, would've spared me from looking like an ass

Comment: @Funkyguy Sorry 'bout that.  I want to use a piezo b/c they are simple to drive (direct connection)

Comment: @Funkyguy I do agree that it would have been best for OP to be explicit

Answer (score 1):

If you do a source transformation on the voltage source and resistor in parallel for the \$8\Omega\$ speaker, you get a current source which is what we care about when driving a speaker. We know that the current through the cap can be written as \$I_c=sCV\$; this means that as the time rate of change of voltage increases, current will increase, and vice versa. The result is that we've protected our speaker from passing too much current and eventually (potentially) being destroyed. Aside from this, impedance of the speaker typically comes into play when we want to maximize the power transfer between an amplifier and the load (speaker). In this case, seems like we don't care too much. A piezoelectric speaker works by virtue of the fact that an applied voltage results in a strain on the material. To my knowledge it is safe to apply the rated amount of DC to one of these, and the high resistance makes it safe to apply this voltage directly without creating enough heat to burn up the device. This circuit should work as expected IMO.

Comment: I'll add that piezo's are *capacitive* loads, not inductive like traditional speakers. [This article](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4164) has some noteworthy things to say about driving them. Most notably, that their impedance is very dynamic!